# Angular 11 + Spring Boot POST header CSRF token not working

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I'm using angular 11 and Spring boot 2.6.1.
I'm applying security changes in my application, I added settings in spring boot side and angular side as well for CSRF token.

Csrf token set in the header at Angular side but I'm not sure why backend still throw 403?

Sample code I have given

At angular side this is app.module.ts file

````
```import {HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { HttpXSRFInterceptor } from './services/my-intercepter';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule
  ],
  providers: [  {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpXSRFInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}```
````

Added this Angular interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpXSRFInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {

  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
    let token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
    if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(headerName)) {
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(headerName, token) });
    }
    return next.handle(req);

  }

}
```

At backend side following code added

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
            
        final CookieCsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        csrfTokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");

        http.httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf()
               .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository);
    }
```

Frontend and backend running on following urls

```
  https://frontend.mydomain.com (frontend)
  https://backend.mydomain.com (backend)
```

Well header is set with X-XSRF-TOKEN from frontend but something is blocking at spring security side.
[image: Header set with X-XSRF-TOKEN]

I'm struggling to resolve this since 5 days, but now I'm clueless, Please just me if anything I missing

Thanks you.

Comment: Could you also share the cookies that are sent in the request? Since you're using `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` you will need to make sure you're sending the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie as well.

Comment: Now I'm able to run this, if I run frontwnd and backend on same localhost, but still it is not working on different server. and this works by removing absolute path of backend api from front-end

Answer (score -2):

Do not change anything on the front side (in Angular) just on the backend just do as the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/users/authenticate")
            .and()
```